# gradle how to exclude duplicated resource files?

Tags: gradle

gradle: how to exclude duplicated resource files? e.g.,

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
             srcDir "../../../src/main/resources"
             exclude "../../../src/main/resources/META-INF/foo.xml"
        }       
    }
}
```

The META-INF/foo.xml under ../../../src/main/resources has the same name as src/main/resources/META-INF/foo.xml.

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/foo.xml
```

Also tried:

```
exclude "META-INF/foo.xml"
```

Both foo.xml files are excluded.

Answer (score 0):

declare as below, basically order the dir in increasing order of priority - the last folder will overwrite.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['overrides/resources', 'src/main/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

in the above ex: if same file name exists `src/main/resources` will win.